# react native error code 500 when use ImageBackground

Tags: react-native

I'm learning react native and have a error
this my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Welcome extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
        <ImageBackground  source={require('./Image_app/welcome.jpg')}  style={styles.container} >
          <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text style={styles.headerText}>
               Setting background image in react native application
             </Text>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
        );
      }
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: null,
    height: null,
    },
    headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold"
    }
});
```

and this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xMzt.png)

a put folder image in my source 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnmat.png)

Comment: Can you share what error you're getting in your terminal.

Comment: module not registered in graph: D:\APK\React_Project\src\Image_app\welcome.jpg

Comment: just added an answer, check if that works and if it does please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the bundler, delete your `node_modules`, reinstall everything by `npm i`, and then start the bundler again. That should resolve your problem.